# How to programmatically read and update a csv file stored in a Github repo?

Tags: python, pandas, github, version-control

I have a csv file stored in a Github repo. I'm reading the data from that csv inside a streamlit app, then based on interactions in the app, want to push the new data to the same csv file stored in the Github repo. The entire interaction in the backend is based on Python/Pandas/Streamlit.
Any idea on how to do that?

I can perfectly read the raw csv file, however the problem occurs when I'm trying to update kit programmatically from the code.

Comment: Do you need to track changes of this CSV file? If not, then I recommend you find a different solution to store the file as this isn't the intended use of GitHub. If you do need the history, then I recommend you check out the GitHub API.

Comment: In general, I would recommend you to use a simple, secure storage service (such as Amazon S3, Google Cloud Object Storage, Microsoft Azure Blob Storage, etc.  — every cloud provider has this offering) which automatically comes with the "versioning" feature for files - thereby you can leverage a cross-industry, well-established solution. GitHub is for code version control and NOT for data version control. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PyGithub` to update the files in `Github` -

```
from github import Github
import requests
import pandas as pd


repo_owner = 'owner_name'
repo_name = 'repository_name'
file_path = 'yourCsvFile.csv'
token = 'token_value'
commit_message = 'Update CSV file'

github = Github(token)
repo = github.get_user(repo_owner).get_repo(repo_name)

url = f'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/main/{file_path}'
response = requests.get(url)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text))
df['test_col'] = "new_test_val"

content = repo.get_contents(file_path)

df.to_csv(/Path/, index=False)


with open(/Path/, 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()


repo.update_file(file_path, commit_message, contents, content.sha)
```